# select2 selected value is not display

Tags: jquery

I am using select2

here is my code:

```
<select name="category" class="select2 select2-offscreen" id="category" style="width:100%" data-placeholder="Select Fields" tabindex="-1">
<option value="">Select Category</option>
<option value="1">Business</option>
<option value="7">Education</option>
<option value="5" selected="selected">Environment</option>
<option value="3">Health</option>
<option value="11">Movies</option>
<option value="4">Science</option>
<option value="2">Sports</option>
<option value="6">Tech</option>
<option value="10">Top Stories</option>      
</select>


$("#category").select2();
```

but it didn't get selected.

any one have idea how to get it working ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Works just fine for me, have you made sure you loaded the libraries correctly, also try hit F12 and check if you get any console errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use like this

```
$("#category").select2().select2("val", 'oneofthevaluehere');
```

Answer (score 1):

Working fine for me, hope you are using this plugin [Select2 - The jQuery replacement for select boxes](https://select2.github.io/)

```js
$(function() {
  $('#category').select2({
    //options
  });
  
  $('#category').on('change', function(){
    console.log('Selected Value : ' + $(this).val() + ' - Selected Text : ' +  $('#category option:selected').text());
  });
  
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />



<select name="category" class="select2 select2-offscreen" id="category" style="width:100%" data-placeholder="Select Fields" tabindex="-1">
<option value="">Select Category</option>
<option value="1">Business</option>
<option value="7">Education</option>
<option value="5" selected="selected">Environment</option>
<option value="3">Health</option>
<option value="11">Movies</option>
<option value="4">Science</option>
<option value="2">Sports</option>
<option value="6">Tech</option>
<option value="10">Top Stories</option>      
</select>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The most likely problem, that could be the reason why you face the problem is that your library is not loaded correctly.

Make sure you load the libraries in the correct order like below:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://select2.github.io/dist/js/select2.full.js"></script>
```

```js
$("#category").select2();
```

```html
<link href="https://select2.github.io/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://select2.github.io/dist/js/select2.full.js"></script>

<select name="category" class="select2 select2-offscreen" id="category" style="width:100%" data-placeholder="Select Fields" tabindex="-1">
<option value="">Select Category</option>
<option value="1">Business</option>
<option value="7">Education</option>
<option value="5" selected="selected">Environment</option>
<option value="3">Health</option>
<option value="11">Movies</option>
<option value="4">Science</option>
<option value="2">Sports</option>
<option value="6">Tech</option>
<option value="10">Top Stories</option>      
</select>
```